# How is difference_type supposed to be used in a non random_access_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

To elaborate, if I cannot do any of this

```
some_iterator it1, it2;
some_iterator::difference_type d = it2 - it1;
it1 += some_iterator::difference_type(42);
```

how am I ever supposed to use (in any useful manner) `difference_type`?

**EDIT** @NathanOliver pointed out pre-allocating sufficient space for some range denoted by a pair of forward iterators is useful. Still looking for uses for input/output iterators

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Comment: And `next`. And `prev`. And `advance`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But how is that number ever going to be used?

Comment: @PasserBy Lets assume you have a sorted linked list and you want to copy the elements that exist in it that are between two items in the list.  You would want to get that amount(distance) to allocate space in the copy-to container.

Comment: @NathanOliver huh, yes. I was originally going to ask about input/output iterators, but then couldn't think of a use for even biderectionals. Are there legit usage for input/output iterators?

Comment: I think this question has degenerated into "give me examples of anything useful that isn't random access", and I don't see how it can possibly be constructive. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Useless I cannot say for sure, I'm in the middle of trying to implement generators (as in Python generators), and modeling them as input iterators. I'm bothered by the fact that no natural difference type arise for certain generators. If there are very legit use cases, I might need to actually be careful about what type I pick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, see [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) and [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance). Just because you can't arithmetically subtract iterators, doesn't mean that the concept of distance between them doesn't exist.

Comment: But the distance is useless in conjunction with the iterator, it is literally just there so you can see it

Comment: @PasserBy What use does the distance between two random access iterators have?

Comment: You can actually randomly access something, for instance a random access iterator on some container can be used to implement a heap, quicksort on a random access iterator is also possible. Actually, there are countless examples

Comment: The standard binary search algorithm `std::lower_bound` can work on non-random-access iterators, using `std::distance` and `std::advance`.  This could potentially be useful for situations where each comparison is extremely expensive (otherwise, a linear search is usually going to be better on non-random-access iterators).

Answer (score 0):

Trivial example for input iterators:

```
template <class InputIterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::reference readNthItem(InputIterator it, typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type n)
{
  std::advance(it, n);
  return *it;
}
```

In general, skipping some items in an input sequence (such as a stream) you're reading is a perfectly valid operation, and you need *some* type for expressing how many steps to skip.